# Display fields name or value and label in drop-down list using prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I am new in prestashop. I want to display all field's labels and its name or value in a drop-down. These fields will be add product form fields. My example is given below.

```
    <select name="select[]" class="form-control advance_select">
          <option value="">- None -</option>
          <optgroup label="Product Information">
          <option value="4">Product ID</option>
          <option value="15">EAN13 or JAN barcode</option>
          <option value="16">UPC barcode</option>
          <option selected="" value="1">Product Name</option>
          <option value="2">Reference code</option>
          <option value="status">Status (Y/N)</option>
          <option value="language">ISO Language</option>
          <option value="iso_code">Currency ISO Code</option>
          <option value="main_category">Name of default Category </option>
          <option value="category_associated">Name of Associated categories </option>
          <option value="17">Product Main Image</option>
          <option value="18">Product Addition Image</option>
          <option value="7">Pre-tax wholesale price</option>
          <option value="8">Pre-tax retail price</option>
          <option value="3">Product Tags</option>
          <option value="5">Product Full Description</option>
          <option value="6">Product Short Description</option>
          <option value="9">Meta title</option>
          <option value="10">Meta description</option>
          <option value="11">Meta keywords</option>
          <option value="12">Friendly URL</option>
          <option value="14">Quantities</option>
          <option value="supplier">Supplier Name</option>
          <option value="manufacturer">Manufacturer Name</option>
     </optgroup>     
    </select>
```

Can I do like this in prestashop? Please help me on this.

Comment: Where do you want to display?